# Openssl command to generate NIST key pair for ECDSA P384 curve

Tags: openssl, ecdsa, nist

Need to know is the command secp384r1 in openssl generates ECDSA key pair based on ECCNIST or ECCSEC standard?

I am using the below command for generating the ECDSA p384 key pair.

openssl ecparam -name secp384r1 -genkey -noout -out private-key.pem
openssl ec -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem

Does the command **secp384r1** generates keys based on NIST standard or SEC standard?
If it is for SEC standard then what is openssl command to generate ECDSA p384 keys in NIST standard?

Comment: The private key is a PEM encoded key in SEC1 format, the public key is a PEM encoded key in X.509/SPKI format. It is possible to identify the format via the header (if the key is valid, which can be assumed for OpenSSL) or via the content, which can be analyzed with an ASN.1 parser. However, this question is off-topic for SO, as it is not programming related.